# How to let java check whether people are friends or not?

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

How do I check whether people are friends or not.

The input would look like

```
Hans Peter
Thomas Peter
Hans Thomas
Kate Thomas
```

Then I will check if Hans Thomas and Peter are friends where the expected output would be "yes"

My idea is to create a bufferedreader that reads a line and a stringtokenizer that takes the inputs from the bufferedreader and puts them in an Arraylist.

Comment: Ok, did you try it? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: execute your plan and then come here

Comment: I don't know how to check whether they are friends or not

Comment: You can use Map<String,List<String>> where each person is mapped by its name to its friend list.

Comment: @user4118143 Give it an attempt, start by reading the data and storing it somehow, if you get stuck after it, come back with the code you managed to write on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Some not perfect solution is to build a map of friends:

```
Map<String, List<String>> friends = new HashMap();

List<String> hansFriends = new ArrayList();
hansFriends.add("Peter");
hansFriends.add("Thomas");
//and so on for each person
//...

//then add friends for "Hans"
peopleFriends.put("Hans", hansFriends);

//repeat for each person: Kate, Thomas
katesFriends = new ArrayList();
katesFriends.add("Thomas");
//...
thomasFriends = new ArrayList();
```

This would translate to the following example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class WhoFriends
{
    /**
     * This is for reading friends. Peter,Hans or Peter; Hans or Peter, Hans works.
     */
    public static final String FRIENDS_PATTERN = "(\\w+)\\W+(\\w+)"; 

    /**
     * We store friends to a map person -> {friends list}
     */
    Map<String, List<String>> friends = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    /**
     * Getter for friends list.
     */
    public Map<String, List<String>> getFriends()
    {
        return friends;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method for friends list.
     */
    public List<String> newFriendsList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Show friends information.
     */
    public void printInfo(String person1, String person2)
    {
        System.out.format("Are %s and %s friends? Answer: %b.%n", person1, person2, areFriends(person1, person2)); 
    }

    /**
     * Show all we have information
     */
    public void showFriends()
    {
        for(String person : getFriends().keySet())
        {
            System.out.format("%s is friends with: %s%n", person, getFriendsList(person).toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This also adds an empty friends list if no list found for the person.
     */
    public List<String> getFriendsList(String person)
    {
        // have an empty list if no friends.
        List<String> friendsList = newFriendsList();

        if (getFriends().containsKey(person))
        {
            friendsList = getFriends().get(person);
        }
        else
        {
            // add empty friends list
            getFriends().put(person, friendsList);
        }

        return friendsList;
    }

    /**
     * Check if a person is friend with another person.
     */
    public boolean isFriendOf(String person, String possiblyAFriend)
    {
        return getFriendsList(person).contains(possiblyAFriend);
    }

    public void makeFriends(String person1, String person2)
    {
        addFriend(person1, person2);
        addFriend(person2, person1);
    }

    public void addFriend(String person, String friend)
    { 
        getFriendsList(person).add(friend);
    }

    /**
     * Two people are friends if they are to each other friends.
     */
    public boolean areFriends(String person1, String person2)
    {
        return isFriendOf(person1, person2) && isFriendOf(person2, person1);
    }

    public void readFriends(String line)
    {
        Pattern friendsExpression = Pattern.compile(FRIENDS_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher           = friendsExpression.matcher(line);
        //Read pairs: Person1, Person2
        if (matcher.find() && (2 == matcher.groupCount()))
        {
            String person1 = matcher.group(1);
            String person2 = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.format("Making friends from %s: %s and %s are friends now.%n",

                    matcher.group(0), 
                    person1,
                    person2);
            makeFriends(person1, person2);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Demonstration :)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WhoFriends wf = new WhoFriends();

        /**
         * Predefine some friendships.
         */
        wf.makeFriends("Hans"  , "Peter");
        wf.makeFriends("Thomas", "Peter");
        wf.makeFriends("Hans"  , "Thomas");
        wf.makeFriends("Kate"  , "Thomas");

        wf.printInfo("Hans"  , "Peter");
        wf.printInfo("Thomas", "Peter");
        wf.printInfo("Hans"  , "Thomas");
        wf.printInfo("Kate"  , "Thomas");
        wf.printInfo("Kate"  , "Peter");
        wf.printInfo("Peter" , "Thomas");

        /**
         * Make friends
         */
        Console console = System.console();
        String  line = null;
        System.out.println("Reading friends. Type in each line Name1,Name2. When you don't want to make more friends type q on the line.");
        /**
         */
        while (!"q".equals(line = console.readLine()))
        { 
            wf.readFriends(line);
        }
        wf.showFriends();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how do you check if some of them are friends?

Comment: @user4118143 you check the map to see a list of friends for a person. The method areFriends(String, String) from the example above. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try a more OO approach by wrapping your person in a Person object maintaining a list of friends for each object. Provide API to add,retrieve and check friendship between two persons.Something like this probably :

```
public interface FriendShip <T>{
    public boolean isFriend(T t);
    public List<T> getFriends();
    public void addFriend(T t);
}


public class Person implements FriendShip<Person> {
    List<Person> friendList = null;

    @Override
    public boolean isFriend(Person t) {
        return friendList.contains(t);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getFriends() {
        return friendList;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFriend(Person newFriend) {
        friendList.add(newFriend);
        if(!newFriend.isFriend(this)){
            newFriend.addFriend(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My idea is to create a buffereader that reads a line and a stringtokenizer that takes the inputs from the buffereader and puts...

Very good so far!

> ...them in an Arraylist.

Targeting your goal, you could think of a better structure... (but at this point I can already welcome you to graph theory!) :-)